# Are the events in Thomas Bernhard’s “Correction” autobiographical?

Tags: german-language, correction, thomas-bernhard

Someone told me today that in “Correction” when Rothaimer “pursue[s] his project of constructing an extraordinary habitation, the Cone” ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_(novel))), that this is based on actual events in Bernhard’s life, that is, as I understood it, that he actually undertook some such construction for his sister. Is this true?  I haven’t found anything that days this to be the case, nor whether he in fact had a sister.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thomas Bernhard had two half-siblings, Peter and Susanna (Susi). While Peter trained as a doctor, and became Bernhard's personal physician for the final decade of his life, I am not aware of a particularly close bond between Thomas and Susanna.

Instead it seems probable that your informant was actually referring to [Wittgenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein), who was the model for Rothaimer, the central character of *Correction*. As David Sepanik noted in his essay *[Reconsidering Thomas Bernhard's Correction](https://web.archive.org/web/20140403053530/http://quarterlyconversation.com/thomas-bernhard-correction)*

> Bernhard based certain bibliographical aspects of Roithamer on the
> life of the Austrian philosopher Ludwig Wittgenstein. Wittgenstein was
> born into great wealth, went to Cambridge, lived austerely, worked
> obsessively, and **spent years carefully designing and building a house
> for his sister** (though it was not cone-shaped).

The house referred to is the *[Haus Wittgenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haus_Wittgenstein)* in Vienna, which still stands, and currently houses the cultural department of the Bulgarian Embassy.